# HTML Background image. Buttons

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a page with a title and 3 buttons. 
I put the background image.But when I put the background, the buttons doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: can you share your code so we have a context?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set the z-index to a higher value, and lower the z-index of the background div that y